# Какие самые быстрые модули для генерации случайных чисел?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Есть например модуль **random**, который я использую, но мне нужен такой модуль, который будет ещё быстрее генерировать случайные числа в цикле.
Вот команда, которую я использую в коде:

```
from random import randint


list_result = [] #Сам список

num_result = 1000000 #Сколько раз я хочу случайных чисел
number_ot = 1 #Начальное случайное число
number_do = 1000000 #Конечное случайное число (очень много нулей)

i = 0
while i < num_result:
            generate = randint(number_ot, number_do)
            list_result.append(generate) #Добавляю в список случайное число
            i += 1
```

Какие вообще есть подобные модули и какой из них быстрее?

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что это именно генерация случайных числе медленная, а не вся остальная часть кода в цикле?

Comment: хм...
В таком случае, а какие вообще способы ускорить этот цикл?
Хотя наверное это надо отдельно спрашивать :/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html — *The underlying implementation in C is both **fast** and threadsafe*. Вряд ли вы найдёте что-то принципиально быстрее

Comment: Хотя нет, тормозит вывод print.

Comment: я вместо принта в своём коде вывожу на графическое приложение модуля QT. Print тут скорее необязателен (удалю в вопросе)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так побыстрее будет

```
from numpy import random

list_result = random.randint(number_do, size=(num_result))
```

Но итоговый список будет массив нампи, а не обычный питонский список.

Comment: есть информация по скорости?

Comment: @Дмитрий На самом деле нет (замерять лениво), и похоже, что разница не такая и большая, если вообще есть.. Если из кода в вопросе убрать print, то он отрабатывает примерно так же быстро, как и нампи

Comment: нашел на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12473924/10562663), задача отличается конечно, но оценка скорости при использовании `numpy`, уж, очень хороша

Comment: @Дмитрий Замерил. На миллионе чисел разница (на моей машине) получается 1,4с против 0.007с. Хотя визуально по ощущениям скрипт выполняется столько же времени. Видимо разные баллстные действия IDLE еще влияют на вывод.

Comment: С random -  0.9364422, а с numpy -   0.0077555
Но тогда мне придётся массив в список превращать, т.к. отображать будет неудобно

Comment: Ну в любом случае, если вам надо выводить такую кучу чисел, то весь затык будет именно в выводе, потому что в питоне это медленная операция, и ускорять генерацию числе здесь большого смысла не имеет. Сократите на полторы секунды, а двести секунд вывода никуда не денутся :)

Comment: `numpy` хорош=) Вынесите вывод в отдельный поток

Comment: А нет, вывелся массив нормально, тогда вопрос уже в скорости вывода, но всё равно помогли. Эти сотые секунды тоже неплохо :)